# wp_get_nav_menu_items wp-admin/customize.php problem

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, navigation

Hello what can I do I somehow get the following error on the custom panel at admin panel. Normally there is no problem on the menu. I only get an error when I enter the Customize page to live the theme live.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Supplied nav_menu_item value missing property: target' in L:\UwAmp\www\Wordpress\News\wp-includes\customize\class-wp-customize-nav-menu-item-setting.php on line 183
```

I take the fault both locally and on the server

**Where I got the error:** wp-admin/customize.php

**Code in function.php file:**

```
 if(!is_admin()){
    add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items', 'display_lasts_ten_posts_for_categories_menu_item', 10, 3 );
}
function display_lasts_ten_posts_for_categories_menu_item( $items, $menu, $args ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        return $items;
    }
    $menu_order = count($items);
    $child_items = array();
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        if ( 'category' != $item->object || ('category' == $item->object && get_category_children($item->object_id)) )
            continue;
        $category_ten_last_posts = array(
                'numberposts' => 4,
                'cat' => $item->object_id,
                'orderby' => 'date',
                'order' => 'DESC'
        );
        foreach ( get_posts( $category_ten_last_posts ) as $post ) {
            $post->menu_item_parent = $item->ID;
            $post->post_type = 'nav_menu_item';
            $post->object = 'header-lasts';
            $post->type = 'header-lasts';
            $post->menu_order = ++$menu_order;
            $post->title = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) . ' ' .$post->post_title;
            $post->url = get_permalink( $post->ID );
            $child_items[]= $post;
        }
    }
    return array_merge( $items, $child_items );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same fatal error after creating a similar dynamic menu. What fixed the issue for me was redefining the default values:

```
$post->target = '';
$post->attr_title = '';
$post->description = '';
$post->classes = '';
$post->xfn = '';
$post->status = 'publish';
$post->original_title = '';
```

So your foreach loop would look like this:

```
foreach ( get_posts( $category_ten_last_posts ) as $post ) {
   $post->menu_item_parent = $item->ID;
   $post->post_type = 'nav_menu_item';
   $post->object = 'header-lasts';
   $post->type = 'header-lasts';
   $post->menu_order = ++$menu_order;
   $post->title = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) . ' ' .$post->post_title;
   $post->url = get_permalink( $post->ID );
   $post->target = '';
   $post->attr_title = '';
   $post->description = '';
   $post->classes = '';
   $post->xfn = '';
   $post->status = 'publish';
   $post->original_title = '';
   $child_items[]= $post;
}
```

Comment: Had exactly the same error, the fix worked. Thx !